# Play music when insert/focus/blur on an input field inside html using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

// I want when you go inside the input field, the music starts playing, when you mouseout the field, the music stops.

// I have the following embed tag inside body of html:

```
<form id="myForm" action="userInfo.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name1" required="required" /> <br />
</form>
<embed src="" autostart="true" loop="true" width="2"     height="0"></embed>
```

// Inside js script:

```
$(document).ready(function()){
    $("#myForm :input").focus(function(){
        $("embed").attr("src", "music/mysong.mp3");
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I tried focus, blur, keyup... it doesn't work.
(If I put the path immediately to the src attribute of embed tag, when you load the page the music starts playing)

Comment: I don't think that approach is likely to work for what you want to do. I think you may need to look at the Web Audio API to achieve that. [This article](https://24ways.org/2013/make-your-browser-dance/) is a good introduction to Web Audio.

Comment: Thank you Matthew... I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new element instead of changing `src`.

```
$(document).ready(function()){
     $("#myForm :input").focus(function(){
         element = $("embed");
         newEl = element.clone().attr("src", "music/mysong.mp3")
         element.replaceWith(newEl);
     });
});
```

Comment: Oh! It works in Chrome (not in Firefox) !! just a little issue... when I go out from the field, the music continues playing. Do u have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is correctly working in my application, just try to use **audio** tag in place of **embed** tag.

```
    <audio id="musicplay" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true">
        <source src="~/music/mysong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
```

and then change your script like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function()){

      $('#musicplay').get(0).pause();

        $("#myForm :input").focus(function(){
             $('#musicplay').get(0).play();
        });
    });
```

You can use .blur() or .focusout() function (which ever works for you) of jquery to stop the music when the control losses focus:

```
  $("#myForm :input").blur(function() {
     $('#musicplay').get(0).pause();
  });
```

Comment: Summer Singh I have the same behavior... it doesn't stop when go out from the field

Comment: I have updated the code to stop the music when you will go out from the field.

Comment: Also this is working in all the browsers as i am using it in my website.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked!!!

```
                 $("#myForm :input").focus(function(){

                    $("embed").attr("src", "music/mysong.mp3");

                    //element = $("embed");
                    newEl = $("embed").clone().attr("src", "music/mysong.mp3");
                    $("embed").replaceWith(newEl);
                });


                $("#myForm :input").focusout(function(){

                    $("embed").attr("src", "");

                    //element = $("embed");
                    newEl = $("embed").clone().attr("src", "");
                    $("embed").replaceWith(newEl);
                });
```

Comment: Works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Unfortunately, weird behavior in IE (pops up a small window of media player and plays there the song). A general question after all is.. ok we found a solution... but why my very first approach of jQuery didn't work? Normally, it should have worked!